# How to udpate nested records containing Maybes using lenses

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

If I have the following types:

```hs
data RecA = RecA 
  { aField1 :: Maybe Text
  , aField2 :: Maybe RecB
  }

data RecB = RecB
  { bField1 :: Maybe Text
  , bField2 :: Maybe Text
  }
```

... and I want to set the value of `bField1` in the following, how do I do it?

```hs
let myVal = Nothing :: Maybe RecA
in set _whatComesHere (Just "ValueFor_bField1") myVal
```

I'm looking for a generalized solution that allows me to set a deeply nested `Maybe a` value irrespective of whether the "parent" data structures are `Nothing`s or `Just`s. I'm fine with defining a `Semigroup`/`Monoid` instance where required.

Comment: have you try something like `_whatComesHere = _Just . aField2 . _Just . bField1`? Not a lens expert but I think it goes on the lines of that.  Probably you can define a custom operator if you reeat a lot the pattern `_Just . lens`

Comment: I'm sort of lost in your example. `myVal` is `Nothing`, so it has no fields to update. You can't just start there and then get provided a `Maybe Text` to use for `bField1` and somehow convert that into a `RecA`. What do you want to happen when `myVal` is `Nothing`? What about when `myVal` is `Just` but `aField2` is `Nothing`?

Comment: Is it really necessary to have so many `Maybe`s? I can think of a couple ways to do this with optics, but the issue is they will be *lawless* optics, since (essentially) they won't tell `Nothing`, `Just (RecA Nothing Nothing)`, and `Just (RecA Nothing (Just (RecB Nothing Nothing)))` apart. It would be cleaner, perhaps, to have `data RecA = RecA { aField1 :: Maybe Text, aField2 :: RecB }; data RecB = RecB { bField1 :: Maybe Text, bField2 :: Maybe Text }`.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @HTNW's comment, there's a bit of conceptual problem here.  Your data types allow the following distinct representations:

```
ex1, ex2, ex3 :: Maybe RecA
ex1 = Nothing
ex2 = Just (RecA Nothing Nothing)
ex3 = Just (RecA Nothing (Just (RecB Nothing Nothing)))
```

but all of these representations *probably* have the same meaning -- a `RecA` with "no fields occupied", right?  Similarly, the two representations:

```
ex4, ex5 :: Maybe RecA
ex4 = Just (RecA (Just "x") Nothing)
ex5 = Just (RecA (Just "x") (Just (RecB Nothing Nothing))
```

probably have the same meaning -- a `RecA` with only the `aField1` occupied.

If so, you should first give consideration to modifying your data types so that multiple representations of the "same `RecA`" aren't possible.

Using alternative types:

```
data RecA = RecA
  { aField1 :: Maybe Text
  , aField2 :: RecB         -- drop the Maybe here
  }

data RecB = RecB
  { bField1 :: Maybe Text
  , bField2 :: Maybe Text
  }
```

and working directly with a `RecA` instead of a `Maybe RecA` gives you the same expressive power, except there's now a unique representation for each possible `RecA`.  A `RecA` with no fields is:

```
ex4 = RecA Nothing (RecB Nothing Nothing)
```

while a `RecA` with only the `aField1` occupied is:

```
ex5 = RecA (Just "x") (RecB Nothing Nothing)
```

With these representations, the `lens`-generated optics work great, and the desired optic for your example is just `aField2.bfield1`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens
import Data.Text (Text)

data RecA = RecA
  { _aField1 :: Maybe Text
  , _aField2 :: RecB
  }

data RecB = RecB
  { _bField1 :: Maybe Text
  , _bField2 :: Maybe Text
  }

concat <$> mapM makeLenses ['RecA, 'RecB]

foo =
  let myVal = RecA Nothing (RecB Nothing Nothing)
  in set (aField2.bField1) (Just "ValueFor_bField1") myVal
```

Without a change in representation, the problem is much harder to solve.

The difficulty is that it's not possible to construct a lawful setter that works correctly over multiple representations of "`Nothing`".  If you require that all `Maybe RecA` values be "normalized" to push all `Nothing` values to the "top" of the structure, then a lawful setter that works only on such normalized values *is* possible, but you would need to take all the `lens`-generated optics (i.e., those generated by `makeLenses` above) and write lots of boilerplate to convert them to the "normalizing" optics you need.  You'd also need a special operator to compose them, because composition with `(.)` wouldn't give you the right optics.

Note that, if your primary justification for having these `Maybe`-filled structures was the convenience of writing:

```
myVal = Nothing :: Maybe RecA
```

in place of:

```
myVal = RecA Nothing (RecB Nothing Nothing)
```

then you might be interested in the `Default` type class in the `data-default` package:

```
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Default

data RecA = RecA
  { _aField1 :: Maybe Text
  , _aField2 :: RecB
  }

data RecB = RecB
  { _bField1 :: Maybe Text
  , _bField2 :: Maybe Text
  }

instance Default RecA where
  def = RecA def def

instance Default RecB where
  def = RecB def def

myVal = def :: RecA   -- same as RecA Nothing (RecB Nothing Nothing)
```